# swift: Get height of any element (iOS 9)

Tags: swift2

How do I get the current height of any element using swift 2?

Any element would be: Buttons, UIImageViews, Labels, Navigation Bars, etc.

Comment: I was tempted to downvote this, too, for lack of research, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious good quality result when Googling `swift get height of element` and that is good enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: zero, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 20)))
print("height = \(view.frame.height)") // prints "height = 20"
```

All elements you listed inherit from `UIView`, so they all have a `frame` property, which has a `height` property.